# Run map function asynchronously on list of unknown size in python with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, batch-processing

I have an application that processes data streamed over tcp in batches. The program is coded in python and I use the asyncio library to switch between the data stream collection and processing.

I need parse the batch line by line and occasionally emit something to the gui. The stream is too fast to send everything. My code currently is

```
 await process_data( list( map( parse_line, await readlines( reader ) ) ) )
```

parse_line will run hundreds of times (depending on how many records readlines returns) and I am locked out since it is a regular function. My initial solution was to try and just asyncio sleep in the parse_line function but python does not like that and throws an error...

```
TypeError: object can't be used in 'await' expression
```

So how do I get around this? I want to be able to switch out while the batch is being processed but I must maintain speed. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

*Update*

simplified code

```
import asyncio 

data = '1,1,1,1\n1,1,1,1\n1,1,1,1\n'

async def readlines(data):
    lines = []
    print('reading data')
    lines =  data.split('\n') 
    return lines 
           
def parse_lines(line):
    print('parsing line')
    print(line)
    ( var1, var2, var3, var4 ) = line.split(',')
    print(f'var1= {var1} var2 = {var2} var3= {var3} var4={var4}')  

async def process_data():
   print(list( map( parse_lines, await readlines( data) )))
```

The goal is to break up the parsing of the data and allow me to get back to my event loop and do other things. I can have 600 items in my data which cause problems since I am trying keep up gui update and a few other things and I am locked out for too long.

Comment: Please show us a minimal working example without typos!

Comment: @KlausD. question updated

Answer (score 1):

`map` function works with "iterable" objects like `list` etc, that is why you get the error, you use `async` function instead of "iterable" object.

If you can accumulate some results, you can do the following:

```py
import asyncio
from random import randint


async def get_randint():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return randint(1, 10)


async def process_data():
    cors = [get_randint() for _ in range(10)]
    r = list(map(lambda x: x**2, await asyncio.gather(*cors)))
    print(r)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(process_data())
```

Note that `await asyncio.gather(*cors))` just returns `list` ("iterable"), so there are no magic results here.

If you get data piece by piece, it will be better to avoid using `map`, and just use `async` `iterator` instead. So probably this example will be useful for you:

```py
import asyncio


async def iterate_async():
    for i in range(1, 11):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
        yield i


async def wait_randint(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
    return i ** 2


async def main():
    return [await wait_randint(i) async for i in iterate_async()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = asyncio.run(main())
    print(x)
```

You can also check this library which provide you with native Python syntax for async operations.

[asyncstdlib](https://github.com/maxfischer2781/asyncstdlib)

There is async map function in this library

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I cannot run your code for some reason in the jupyter notebook I am getting `TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got list
` I also updated my question with a bit more detail.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice what Python version do you use? `iterate_async` provides `__aiter__` but just with another syntax

Comment: @TheCodeNovice as far as I can see in your example you have no need to use map, just read line by line (e.g. get smth from network), process it and then append result to results `list`

Comment: Kozyrev Speed though. This is a snippet from a larger code. I get batches that are very larger and I know loops are slow. The list comprehension is fast.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice loops = list comprehension = syntax sugar, e.g. list comprehension does not exist in `C` language. You can not use list comprehension because your data is not available at once, that's why you just add results on "ready basis". And `asyncio` is not about loops and list comprehension.

Comment: But the data comes in batches over tcp so I do have it all at once. I think I have read post that list comprehension is indeed different vs a for loop. What I am showing simplified to focus in on the point of using an awaitable function in map. I will check out that library you posted though.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice sorry, but in batches != at once ))